# Duplicate Search Broken?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

When trying to flag a question as a duplicate, you used to be able to paste in a link and the dialog box would find the question via the link. As of now, I can only get it to work by pasting in the question number. Did something change? I have already flagged the duplicate question and can't return to the dialog to actually show you the question that had the problem. [This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781520/java-adjacent-comparing-and-calculating-frequency-of-words?noredirect=1#comment32953772_21781520) I tried to flag but I had to put the post ID 21771566 to get the box to trigger and let me flag it.

(Note: I know this question is not a duplicate of the one I selected, it is just an example)

[image]